# Hide subdir in displayed URL via .htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My client's domain name points to /public_html; his website is at /public_html/wp.
I have a .htaccess that redirects to /public_html/wp:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?somedmain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?somedmain\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ /wp/ [L]
```

However, when the user navigates to a page, the url is displayed as somedmain.com/wp/permalink.

I've been trying to figure how to hide the "wp" in the url; is that possible?
Thanks for any hints....

Comment: Maybe this link helps http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory, no mod_rewrite involved though.

Comment: Thanks, faa, I think that's the answer.